# Javascript invoking function via anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to do something like FB 'Like' style of clicking but I have a problem in invoking the anchor link.

```
<li id="vote-ico"><a class="unlike" href="javascript:void(0)">Unlike</a></li>
<li id="vote-ico"><a class="like" href="javascript:void(0)">Like</a></li>
```

But the following JS is not working.

```
$('.unlike').click(function(){
   alert($(this));
   $(this).removeClass('unlike').addClass('like', function(){
        //action
    }).text('like');
})

$('.like').click(function(){
   alert($(this));
 $(this).removeClass('like').addClass('unlike', function(){
        //action
    }).text('unlike');
})
```

It does not even alert! Can someone help me??

Comment: Where is your JS code in relation to your HTML? This code needs to execute **after** your HTML is ready/rendered

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/WxuVn/ - the way you were forming your alert was incorrect.

Comment: @andrew-buchan There's nothing wrong with the `alert`. It has to do with the binding

Comment: couple of things..1 wrap your code in `ready handler`,2. Use event delegation if nescessary

Comment: You can use ajax technology.

Comment: T@Ian the alert display [object:Object] - not what the OP wanted. I agree that the binding is the issue but the alert was coded incorrectly too.

Comment: @andrew-buchan No, the OP said `It does not even alert!`. They didn't specify what they want it to say, it's unrelated.

Comment: @Mouse Tan: In your code you bind the click event of `unlike` and `like`. but you never `unbind` it. When you `removeClass` of `<a>` tag it only remove element class, but the click event is always bind with `element`. So resolve this problem you need to `unbind` it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.like').click(function(e){
       alert($(this));
     $(this).removeClass('like').addClass('unlike', function(){
            //action
        }).text('unlike');
    })
});
```

Put it in a document ready to ensure that there are no timing issues. The .click handler can't be attached until the element is on the page.

You can however use .on if you need to attach the handler before the element is present

```
$("#someParent").on("click",".like",function(){alert(''test)});
```

Comment: `href="javascript:void(0)`, and this wouldn't do anything either, because the `alert` would hold the navigation

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your code with document.ready:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.unlike').click(function(){
       alert($(this));
       $(this).removeClass('unlike').addClass('like', function(){
            //action
        }).text('like');
    })

    $('.like').click(function(){
       alert($(this));
     $(this).removeClass('like').addClass('unlike', function(){
            //action
        }).text('unlike');
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you bind the click event of `unlike` and `like`. but you never `unbind` it. When you `removeClass` of `<a>` tag it only remove element class, but the click event is always bind with your `element`

Try this-

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
 $('.lnkClick').click(function(){    
   alert($(this).text());
    if($(this).text() == "Unlike"){
        $(this).text('like');
    }
    else{
       $(this).text('Unlike');
    }       
 });
});
```

[Try JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G2Phs/1/)

Use `onclick` of `<a>` tag -

HTML -

```
<li id="vote-ico"><a class="unlike" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="LikeIt($(this));">Unlike</a></li>
<li id="vote-ico"><a class="like" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="LikeIt($(this));">Like</a></li>
```

Jquery -

```
function LikeIt(Obj){
    if(Obj.attr('class') == "unlike"){
      Obj.removeClass('unlike').addClass('like', function(){
        //action
      }).text('like');
    }
    else{
      Obj.removeClass('like').addClass('unlike', function(){
        //action
      }).text('unlike');
    }
}
```

[Try this with onClick](http://jsfiddle.net/23WMp/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<li id="vote-ico"><a name="unlike" class="likeUnlike like" href="javascript:void(0)">Unlike</a></li>
</ul>


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.likeUnlike').click(function(){
    var status=$(this).attr('name');
        if(status=='unlike')
        {
            var $this= $(this)
            $this.removeClass('liked').addClass('unlike');
            $this.attr('name','like');
            $this.text('unliked');
        }
        else{
         var $this= $(this)
            $this.removeClass('unlike').addClass('like');
            $this.attr('name','unlike');
            $this.text('liked');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/zeewon/TKZn6/3/

and regarding your html :if you are using two li tags they should have different id .
this will fit your requirement please see the demo.thanks